# Sending message using SocketIO failing, not updating on window or other side too

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am unable to send message using socketio, Here's an function i am using but not able to send messages.

Following is the flow I am using, event wise

```
workspace_room_join
get_user_room
room_join
message
```

Now I am unable to send a message, What is the correct way to send the message?

Below code function is for sending message

```
sendUsingSocket = (messages) => {
    const workspace_id = localStorage.getItem('workspace_id');
    const payload = {
      room_id:this.props.socket_details.room_id,
      isChannel:false,
      workspace_id:workspace_id,
      chat: messages,
      sender_id: this.state.sender_to_receiver_details.sender_id,
      receiver_id: this.state.sender_to_receiver_details.receiver_id,
    }
      socket.emit("message", payload);
}
```

and here is the component I am passing

```
 <Chat sendUsingSocket={this.sendUsingSocket} />
```

And here is my Component did mount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("Auth");
    const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getUserInfoFromLocalStorage"));
    const user_id = userInfo._id
    if(token !== undefined){
      socket.emit("workspace_room_join",{
        workspace_id:user_id,
        token:token
      })
      socket.on("workspace_room_join",(data) => {
      })
    }
    socket.on("get_user_room", (data) => {
      this.props.actions.savingRoomId(data)
    })
    socket.on("room_leave", () => {
        socket.emit("room_join", {
            room_id: this.props.socket_details.room_id,
        })
    })
    socket.on("get_user_room", (data) => {
      socket.emit("room_join", {
        room_id: data.room_id,
    })
    });
    socket.on("message",(data) => {
     const message_details =  data.chatData
    this.setState({
      listen_messages:message_details
    })
    })
    localStorage.setItem('workspace_id',this.props.match.params.id)
    this.props.actions.getByWorkspaceId({ id: this.props.match.params.id });
    let {actions} = this.props;
    actions.fetchChannelList()
    actions.fetchUserlist()
  }
```

I am unable to send messages, how to fix that?

Comment: Can you share your code for socket server, is there a handler for listening to messages there?

Comment: @Gaurav Here is the code, I've pasted in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dubinsky-3idjk  please help me getting the right structure of that file. Seems like I have many wrong configuration. It would really helpful if you are able to re-write the file as per working of socket and message